# How do I get floating label to float in view before dialogfragment is launched?

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I have three floating labels for three EditTexts that work fine on a UI screen.
The fourth EditText does not float the hint until *after* the listener launches and closes (dismisses) a dialogfragment.  I am trying to have the hint float *right after* the EditText gains focus, and *before* the dialogfragment is launched, so the user can see the completed hint floated before getting additional information from the dialogfragment.  The fourth EditText has the "hasFocus" code shown below whereas the first three EditTexts do not so something with the hasFocus is preventing the label from floating right away, although it eventually does after the diaglogfragment is closed.  Please advise.

Activity.java

```
....
private ListenerEditText fListenerEditText;
fListenerEditText = (ListenerEditText) findViewById(R.id.FEditText);
fListenerEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, final boolean hasFocus) {
           if(hasFocus) {
                DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
       }
    }
}); ...
```

layout file.xml

```
...
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/DueDate_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_row="4"
    android:layout_column="0">

<com.example.jdw.thirdscreen.ListenerEditText
    android:id="@+id/FEditText"
    android:hint="Due Date"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal|start"
    android:inputType="text|textCapSentences|textNoSuggestions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="51"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext|flagNoExtractUi"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"  >

</com.example.jdw.thirdscreen.ListenerEditText>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```